# How to re-enable all screen lock types after uninstalling OpenVPN connect?

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN Connect on my Samsung Galaxy S4. The app forced me to pick a screen lock, which I set to PIN.

However, I've cleared all application data regarding to OpenVPN Connect and also uninstalled the app, but I'm not able to select 'none' as screen lock type. Only pattern, PIN and password are available in settings as shown:

[image: Select screen lock in settings]

Is there a way to get all the selections available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern, PIN or Password screen lock is required, because there were still user certificates stored in the device.

Go to Settings -> Security and pick Clear credentials.